# Google Apps Jdbc - Connection Issue

Tags: jdbc, connection

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server using Jdbc for Google Apps and getting an error as follows:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string,
>   username and password. (line 10, file "dbadmin")

The following is a snipet of the code I am using:

```
var address = 'w.x.y.z';

var user = 'user';

var userPwd = 'password';

var db = 'dbname';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
```

I have successfully connected to the Database from my own computer using both the IP and Hostname. I have confirmed the server should be accepted connections from ALL IPs for that account, and confirmed the ruleset is working by removing the whitelisting and adding it back again.

I am basically out of troubleshooting ideas of what is going on. What am I doing wrong, or what is wrong with Google?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be in Java. Also you need to specify the port number of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to establish JDBC connection is as follows:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/mydb";
String username = "username";
String password = "password"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

You can refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, but this is with specifically with the Google Apps version of JDBC.